# Who is this actor? Talks out of the right side of his face

Tags: identify-this-actor

Okay, so this has been eating me alive all night. There is an actor who I like, but can't remember his name, or even what I've seen him in. I know, I know; I must no like him very much, then. Well, he's fun. Anyway, let me describe him and the roles he has played (it should make this question very search-friendly):

- He talks almost exclusively out of the right side of his face. That is to say, he seems to angle his mouth 20-35 degrees to his right every time he says something.
- He is caucasian and from either Canada or the U.S.
- He is short-ish. I would say he's maybe 5'5"-5'7"
- He is also plump-ish, and has a noticeable slouch to his neck
- He has seemingly greasy, black hair, which is almost always combed down straight into his face, but is relatively short.
- He has a very prominent nose.
- I have only ever seen him in television shows.
- He has played, from what I can remember: A mayor, a presidential or congressional(can't remember which) candidate, and various office-worker roles.
- He has played serious characters and quirky, silly characters.
- His roles are usually integral to the story arc, but are never main-characters. As in, he often helps the main character, or provides a short-term antagonist.
- He likes to sit with his elbows on a table and his hands draped over one another in front of his neck/face. Often gesticulates, but not wildly.
- His voice has a relatively nasal quality to it.
- Is in his late 40s to mid 50s.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haycL41dAhg&list=PL61E606149255B362&feature=share&index=2) is actually the reason it's been eating me alive. The lecturer in this series looks like a skinnier version of the actor, down to the talking out of the side of his face and the prominence of his nose. It's stupid, but that doesn't make it any less nagging. The lecturer looks so much like the actor that they could be the same person; the lecturer being a younger version. They look so similar that I actually tried to see if the lecturer was related to any actors.

Comment: For a few details, I would have said Robert de Niro, but he's played a lot of main characters. Is it old/young? Made me thought also of Eric Roberts, but he's quite tall...

Comment: It's definitely not Robert de Niro or Eric Roberts. :P Adding approximate age to post.

Comment: I didn't realize you had found who you were looking for! I posted an answer of [David Hewlett](http://youtu.be/GAxwZJ2U_JI), but deleted it. Glad you found him!

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to add the answer once I'm able (can't for 8 hours after asking). Unless someone else wants to post the answer. -shrug-

Comment: I wouldn't call Richard Kind `short-ish`. I remember that on [Spin City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115369/) only _Barry Bostwick_ was taller than him.

Comment: I didn remember him from Spin City, which is weird because I loved that show. But everything else h e is in he is typically sitting down or at an angle that allows the viewer to see the protagonists face, making him look shorter than he is. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow. I finally found him. I was going through my Netflix history, and checking every show that I thought he might have been a part of, scrolling down lists of actors with tiny pictures next to them on IMDB. Finally I got to *Burn Notice*. He played a character named Marv in four episodes in 2010. his name:

[Richard Kind](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0454236/)

[image: Richard Kind]

Nick Parlante (lecturer in video)

[image: Nick Parlante]

He doesn't look as much like the person in the video as I thought, and I underestimated his age a little. Still, their mannerisms and even their hairline are almost identical. He's also a LOT taller than I thought he was. He looked pretty short in every show I saw him in, but I guess that was a camera trick to make the main characters look taller.

Answer (score 1):

From your clip, I'd say it could be... [Joaquin Phoenix](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001618/?ref_=tt_cl_t1), which would be ironic as I just posted a question about a film he's been in recently. Although, he has played mainly lead roles and I don't recall him doing any of the roles you spoke of.

He does seem to talk out the side of his face a little though?

P.S. If its not Joaquin Phoenix, is he a present day actor?

Comment: It is not him, but that is a much closer match to the person I'm thinking of. Yes, the actor I'm looking for is a present day actor. He looks a little younger than Phoenix. Also, I need to add that he has _black_ hair to teh question

Comment: okay, does he do TV & Films? Also, are the roles you mentioned TV roles?

Comment: As far as I know, he does TV. I don't think I have seen him in a movie, but I can't be sure.

Comment: An American actor?

Comment: Definitely American or Canadian. Basically, North American. Let me add that to the question

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be talking about the actor John Billingsley.   I most recently  have seen him play the role of Samuel Townsend  him in AMC's TV show TURN: Washington's Spies.

[image]